# Can't connect to VPN on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, vpn, openvpn, devices

I am new to Ubuntu. I have configured VPN set-up on Ubuntu 14.04 but could not connect. System log shows following errors:

```
Jun 28 13:35:50 rana-laptop kernel: [ 9723.920954] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
Jun 28 13:35:50 rana-laptop kernel: [ 9723.923177] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
Jun 28 13:35:50 rana-laptop kernel: [ 9723.923186] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jun 28 13:36:10 rana-laptop pppd[11154]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Jun 28 13:36:10 rana-laptop pppd[11154]: Connection terminated.
Jun 28 13:36:10 rana-laptop avahi-daemon[477]: Withdrawing workstation service for ppp0.
Jun 28 13:36:10 rana-laptop NetworkManager[857]:  VPN plugin failed: 1
Jun 28 13:36:10 rana-laptop NetworkManager[857]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Jun 28 13:36:10 rana-laptop pppd[11154]: Modem hangup
Jun 28 13:36:10 rana-laptop NetworkManager[857]:  VPN plugin failed: 1
Jun 28 13:36:15 rana-laptop pppd[11154]: Child process /usr/sbin/pptp 202.191.127.194 --nolaunchpppd --loglevel 0 --logstring nm-pptp-service-11148 (pid 11156) terminated with signal 15
Jun 28 13:36:15 rana-laptop pppd[11154]: Exit.
Jun 28 13:36:15 rana-laptop NetworkManager[857]:  VPN plugin failed: 1
Jun 28 13:36:15 rana-laptop NetworkManager[857]:  VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
Jun 28 13:36:15 rana-laptop NetworkManager[857]:  VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Jun 28 13:36:15 rana-laptop NetworkManager[857]:  Policy set 'SYMPHONY W90' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Jun 28 13:36:15 rana-laptop NetworkManager[857]:  error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Jun 28 13:36:20 rana-laptop NetworkManager[857]:  VPN service 'pptp' disappeared
Jun 28 13:36:42 rana-laptop kernel: [ 9775.637094] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
Jun 28 13:36:42 rana-laptop kernel: [ 9775.639341] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
Jun 28 13:36:42 rana-laptop kernel: [ 9775.639349] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jun 28 13:37:34 rana-laptop kernel: [ 9827.349249] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
Jun 28 13:37:34 rana-laptop kernel: [ 9827.351489] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
Jun 28 13:37:34 rana-laptop kernel: [ 9827.351494] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jun 28 13:37:46 rana-laptop pptp[11160]: nm-pptp-service-11148 warn[open_inetsock:pptp_callmgr.c:329]: connect: Connection timed out
Jun 28 13:37:46 rana-laptop pptp[11160]: nm-pptp-service-11148 fatal[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:127]: Could not open control connection to 202.191.127.194
Jun 28 13:37:46 rana-laptop pptp[11158]: nm-pptp-service-11148 fatal[open_callmgr:pptp.c:487]: Call manager exited with error 256

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I don't understand what went wrong.

Please help.